# Change the appearance of gridview

Tags: asp.net, grid, asp.net-controls

I have a News table in DB that contain (id,title,body) fields.
Now I want to display these news into news.aspx page.
I can use grid view to show them, but i want to change the grid view's appearance,like below image.how can do it?or any idea for this.
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `ListView` may be? Or any `TemplateField`?

Comment: U can use `UpdatePanel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Listview to implement as follows:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvNewsContent" runat="server">
     <LayoutTemplate>
      <div style="border:1px solid black; border-top:2px solid black; text-align:center; width:200px; height:60px;">
        <%#Eval("NewsTitle") %>
      </div>
      <div style="border:1px solid black; width:200px; text-align:center; display:block;">
          <div style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; text-align:center;">
            <%#Eval("NewsDetail") %>
        </div>
        <div style="width:60px; height:20px; float:right; margin-right:20px;">
            More info
        </div>
    </div>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

After that set the Data source  of Listview and then bind it.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView control is capable of [displaying images for customize appearance](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/gridview_style_appearance_image.shtml) to indicate the status of a grid row by using a few properties within the KetticGridView.